# Apache Camel - SedaEndpoint

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm trying to send a message to an async route but it's not working.
I have just created a projeto on github to simulate the problem

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SedaQueueApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
@EndpointInject(uri = "direct://direct-queue")
ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SedaQueueApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
    producerTemplate.sendBody("Teste Direct - Async");
}

@Component
class Router extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct://direct-queue").routeId("toAsync").to("seda://async-queue?size=100");

        from("seda://async-queue").routeId("toLog").log("${body}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, Don't put links to other projects. Very few people will look into those links. Instead put the actual problem with relavant code and exception/stacktrace.

Comment: Sorry for that I will edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you have two routes. In one of the route you have specified `seda://async-queue` and in other `seda://async-queue?size=100` make this consistent i.e. add size attribute to first route or remove from second. It will work like a peach.
2. The reason for this is (Not sure if it is a bug in camel code), In `SedaComponent::getOrCreateQueue` they are comparing for size attribute also. Hence you get an exception if the size attribute if present and doeśn't match.

Hope that helps.